# Excel VBA : Not responding Or Ultra long runtime with DoEvents

Tags: vba, excel

Hi everyone and thanks for reading !

I've looked for answers to my problem but didn't found enough...

Here is the idea of my code : In a table there is a number of column (chambre) and a number of row (alveole).  If these matches in a list in an other sheet then it checks if it the date is between two dates on that second sheets. If it matches those 3 things, then it puts the sheet

My code works if i add "DoEvents" in every For, else excel and vba stops responding. But it takes aroung 5 minutes and i need to to this for 4 tables...

Is it my code that is not efficient ? Do you have any ideas how to make it better ? Any advices is appreciated !

Here is the code

```
Sub alveoles()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Dim moment As Date
'variables Photo
Dim four As Integer
Dim chambre As Integer
Dim alveole As Integer
Dim aaa As Integer
Dim ccc As Integer

'variables Gems
Dim ligne As Integer
Dim enfournement As Date
Dim defournement As Date

Dim lastrow As Integer


'set date and lastrow
moment = Worksheets("Photo").Range("O2").Value
lastrow = Worksheets("Gems").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
four = 1
'Four1 1 row
For ligne = 2 To lastrow
DoEvents

            For chambre = 1 To 38
            DoEvents
                For alveole = 1 To 6
                 DoEvents

                enfournement = Worksheets("Gems").Range("D" & ligne).Value
                defournement = Worksheets("Gems").Range("E" & ligne).Value

                If four = Worksheets("Gems").Range("A" & ligne).Value And _
                   chambre = Worksheets("Gems").Range("B" & ligne).Value And _
                   alveole = Worksheets("Gems").Range("C" & ligne).Value And _
                    moment > enfournement And _
                    moment < defournement Then

                                aaa = alveole + 5
                                ccc = chambre + 2

                            Worksheets("Photo").Cells(aaa, ccc).Interior.ColorIndex = 1 'NOIR

                End If
                Next alveole
            Next chambre
Next ligne

End Sub
```

Comment: If your code ultimately works and all you're looking for is ways to make it better and cleaner, you might be interested in [codereview.se].

Comment: Do you know about `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlManual`?

Comment: How many lines is in "Gems"?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you are concerned about Excel having crashed (Not responding, DoEvents) when it is actually just calculating. Have you considered using a UserForm progress bar or status bar updates to reassure you that the macro is still running without using DoEvents?

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for the quick answers !
Mat'sMug Thanks I will check this out.
puzzlepiece87 I knew about screenupdating but it doesnt do much. Will try the two! Thanks!
Roland 6859 for now but it is variable
@puzzlepiece87, No but I will ! But i'm pretty sure the code crashes forever when I don't put DoEvents

Comment: Sounds good, let me know if you need help finding a tutorial to either use a Userform as a progress bar or to update Excel's status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your code that your end goal is to simply set the format of a cell under certain conditions, then I think VBA is unnecessary here and you should consider using Conditional Formatting. It is built in to Excel, is lightening fast and easier to maintain.

If you can make your data into Excel tables (Ribbon: Format as Table), then the Conditional Formatting will automatically copy down for each new row you add.

Check out this Microsoft support article to show you how it's done.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-in-Excel-2013-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA